# django import settings problem

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, import, settings

This seems to be a common problem for many others, but none of the other fixes have helped me. Here's my apache2/sites-available file:

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE getgps.settings
    PythonOption django.root /
    PythonDebug On
</Location>

Alias /media/css /home/getgps/media/css
<Location "/media/css">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```

And the error message:

```
Error: Could not import settings 'code.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings
```

settings.py is located in /home/getgps/code/settings.py and /home/getgps/code is linked such that it is getgps in the python environment (if I type import getgps.settings into a command line it imports the file in question independent of where I am when I load the python command line).

**tldr: sybolic link works, apache file is great, but it doesn't seem to like my file structure.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to comment out:

```
PythonOption django.root /
```

as it is not needed (and doesn't work in this case). You only need to use this line if your site is not at DocRoot.

Obs: if you can it is recommended to switch from mod_python to mod_wsgi but not all providers accept it as it needs restarting apache sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally just moved the code into the parent directory (and redid the symbolic link) and it worked fine. I have no idea why it wasn't working. The previous code bases I've worked on were all set up like this...